# Allow IAP on applications running on Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I currently have different web application running in Compute engine using an external IP.(everyone can connect and even login if they have the correct information)

I would like to enable IAP to project those webpage.

By enabling IAP for https request then would I have to create a load balancer per application? Do I need to have a load balancer?

Or can I just redirect all incoming traffic to an IAP authentication page just like it is done for ssh and rdp which we are using.